# SMS messages won't delete no matter what

Tags: sms, delete, samsung-galaxy-y

I have a phone which has thousands of SMS. Now it's very difficult to delete them all and the SMS app always hangs. I have tried the following to no avail:

- Select All SMS > Delete
- Downloaded [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) App and used it's delete function
- Downloaded [Super SMS Quick Delete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superdroid.sqd) App and used it's delete function

They all just hang.

I am also trying to "Clear Data" the Dialer Storage App but it's not pressable, even after "Force Stop". How can I make the Clear Data button pressable?

Or, is there another way to delete all SMS aside from Factory Reset?

Comment: When you say they hang, are you sure they're not just working?

Comment: @DanHulme Yes, I left it overnight, it deleted very few amount of SMS. Tried it again, doesn't delete anymore. Maybe it's stuck on some corrupt SMS.

Comment: Reposted from a comment by Gretchen Hollinger: Did anyone ever figure out this issue? Here it is, 2015, and I'm having the exact same problem. I've emailed the developer and left a poor review in the app Play Store, hoping to get a response. If I deleted these messages manually, it might only take 10 minutes, so why can't the app do it? And before anyone asks, yes, I did change my default messaging app to SMS Backup & Restore.

Answer (score 1):

You could always download Handcent and use its "Force Deletion" feature. I've seen that work for many others. But depending on how many SMS you have, you will need to let it sit for a while.